# Need help including only specific rows in my data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query in SQL Server where I pull an employee's number, type of position, status in that position and the most recent assignment date.  Employee's can have more than one Status (A, T, L) and I want to include all rows with a status of A and L; but for those employees that have a Status of T (and they could have more than one row) I only want to include them if the LastDate was within the last 60 days (and if there is more than one row within the last 60 days pull the most recent).

Can anyone help with this?

```
SELECT        dbo.EMPLOYEE.EMPLOYEENUMBER, dbo.CODE.DESCRIPTION, dbo.ASSIGNMENT.STATUS,  MAX(dbo.ASSIGNMENT.TIMESTAMP) 
                         AS LASTDATE
FROM            dbo.EMPLOYEE INNER JOIN
                         dbo.ASSIGNMENT ON dbo.EMPLOYEE.ID = dbo.ASSIGNMENT.EMPLOYEE_ID INNER JOIN
                         dbo.V_PERSONTOPROFILE ON dbo.ASSIGNMENT.ID = dbo.V_PERSONTOPROFILE.assignmentId RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.ATTRIBUTEINSTANCE INNER JOIN
                         dbo.CODE ON dbo.ATTRIBUTEINSTANCE.VALUE = dbo.CODE.CODE INNER JOIN
                         dbo.ASSIGNMENT_ATTRIBUTEINSTANCE ON dbo.ATTRIBUTEINSTANCE.ID = dbo.ASSIGNMENT_ATTRIBUTEINSTANCE.attributeInstances_ID ON 
                         dbo.ASSIGNMENT.ID = dbo.ASSIGNMENT_ATTRIBUTEINSTANCE.Assignment_ID
WHERE        (dbo.ASSIGNMENT.STATUS IN ('A', 'L', 'T')) AND (dbo.CODE.CODEGROUP_ID = 4979)
GROUP BY dbo.EMPLOYEE.EMPLOYEENUMBER,  dbo.CODE.DESCRIPTION, dbo.ASSIGNMENT.STATUS
```

Here is a section of the results that are returned:

[image]

0016, 0017 and 0018 shouldn't pull in as the date is greater than 60 days from today
0019 - has both an A and T; but since A is the most recent date that row should pull in
0023 - has (3) T's; but the last row should pull in since it has a date of 10/15/2023

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
thanks

I've tried using the GetDate(), a nested join and subqueries; but it's just not correct.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question as text, no images.

Comment: So if there are multiple records for an employee with either `A` or `L` status, you want all those records, right? And only for the `T` status you want to check for the most recent `LASTDATE` being within 60 days, is that correct?

Comment: NOT part of your question but `MAX(dbo.ASSIGNMENT.TIMESTAMP)`  would be a terrible column name for something that appears to be a `DATE` TYPE - hence clarity with the DDL  and sample data would greatly help here  You do not ever appear to do anything to resolve the **I only want to include them if the LastDate was within the last 60 days** part in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to include all rows with a status of A and L; but for those employees that have a Status of T (and they could have more than one row) I only want to include them if the LastDate was within the last 60 days

This:

```
AND dbo.ASSIGNMENT.STATUS IN ('A', 'L', 'T')
```

becomes this:

```
AND (
    dbo.ASSIGNMENT.STATUS IN ('A', 'L')
    OR ( dbo.ASSIGNMENT.STATUS = 'T'  AND dbo.ASSIGNMENT.TIMESTAMP >= DATEADD(day, -60, current_timestamp) )
)
```

or (assuming none of the `A` or `L` timestamps are `NULL`) this:

```
AND dbo.ASSIGNMENT.STATUS IN ('A', 'L', 'T')
AND dbo.ASSIGNMENT.TIMESTAMP >= CASE WHEN dbo.ASSIGNMENT.STATUS = 'T' THEN DATEADD(day, -60, current_timestamp) ELSE '19000101' END
```

Note these options look at individual timestamps, rather than the aggregate. But since we roll up the rows to only show the largest date at the end, and we're also doing a > comparison, this will work out to still show the correct result.

I suspect you might also want to do just a little more work to always keep the full day when going 60 days back, but I'll leave that as an exercise.

Combine it with my community wiki notes to get this:

```
SELECT e.EMPLOYEENUMBER, c.DESCRIPTION, a.STATUS,  
    MAX(a.TIMESTAMP) AS LASTDATE
FROM dbo.ATTRIBUTEINSTANCE ai
INNER JOIN dbo.CODE c ON ai.VALUE = c.CODE
INNER JOIN dbo.ASSIGNMENT_ATTRIBUTEINSTANCE aai ON ai.ID = aai.attributeInstances_ID 
INNER JOIN dbo.ASSIGNMENT a ON a.ID = aai.Assignment_ID
INNER JOIN dbo.EMPLOYEE e ON e.ID = a.EMPLOYEE_ID
INNER JOIN dbo.V_PERSONTOPROFILE pp ON a.ID = p.assignmentId 
WHERE c.CODEGROUP_ID = 4979
    AND a.STATUS IN ('A', 'L', 'T')
    AND a.TIMESTAMP > CASE WHEN a.STATUS = 'T' THEN DATEADD(day, -60, current_timestamp) ELSE '19000101' END
GROUP BY e.EMPLOYEENUMBER, c.DESCRIPTION, a.STATUS
```

---

##### Alternate interpration:

> 0016, 0017 and 0018 shouldn't pull in as the date is greater than 60 days from today
> 0019 - has both an A and T; but since A is the most recent date that row should pull in
> 0023 - has (3) T's; but the last row should pull in since it has a date of 10/15/2023

Based on this, we want to "pre-qualify" some rows, such that ANY `A` or `L` row for an employee from the last 60 days would qualify ALL `T` rows for the same employee, but only if it's the most recent row for that employee. A `T` row from the last 60 days can only qualify itself.

To do this, we'll join the main part of query to itself, use row_number() to prioritize the qualifying rows (since there could be multiple), only keep rows with the highest priority, and look at the timestamp from the qualifying row.

```
WITH base AS (
    SELECT e.EMPLOYEENUMBER, c.DESCRIPTION, a.STATUS,  
        MAX(a.TIMESTAMP) AS LASTDATE
    FROM dbo.ATTRIBUTEINSTANCE ai
    INNER JOIN dbo.CODE c ON ai.VALUE = c.CODE
    INNER JOIN dbo.ASSIGNMENT_ATTRIBUTEINSTANCE aai ON ai.ID = aai.attributeInstances_ID 
    INNER JOIN dbo.ASSIGNMENT a ON a.ID = aai.Assignment_ID
    INNER JOIN dbo.EMPLOYEE e ON e.ID = a.EMPLOYEE_ID
    INNER JOIN dbo.V_PERSONTOPROFILE pp ON a.ID = p.assignmentId 
    WHERE c.CODEGROUP_ID = 4979
    AND a.STATUS IN ('A', 'L', 'T')
    GROUP BY e.EMPLOYEENUMBER, c.DESCRIPTION, a.STATUS
)
, combined As (
    SELECT b.*, q.TimeStamp as QualifyingStamp,
        row_number() over (
            PARTITION BY b.EmployeeNumber, b.Description, b.Status
            ORDER BY CASE 
                WHEN q.Status IN ('A', 'L') AND q.TimeStamp > DATEADD(day, -60, current_timestamp) THEN 0
                WHEN q.TimeStamps > DATEADD(day, -60, current_timestamp) THEN 1 
                ELSE 2 END
        ) rn
    FROM base b
    INNER JOIN base q ON q.EmployeeNumber = b.EmployeeNumber AND q.Description = b.DESCRIPTION
        AND coalsece(nullif(b.Status, 'T'), q.Status) = q.Status
    
)
SELECT *
FROM combined
WHERE rn = 1 
    AND (Status IN ('A', 'L') OR QualifyingStamp > dateadd(day, -60, current_timestamp) )
```

I don't expect this is the most efficient query out there. I could probably greatly improve it with more time, but this is what you get for free.

Comment: Thank you so much for this help Joel!  This was amazing!  After reviewing your response I jumped onto LinkedIn and took a SQL Server class (my background is with Oracle) so I could better understand some of the differences between the two that you outlined above.  I appreciate the very detailed process you outlined above.

Answer (score 0):

I took a moment to reformat the query in a way that's actually readable:

```
SELECT e.EMPLOYEENUMBER, c.DESCRIPTION, a.STATUS,  
    MAX(a.TIMESTAMP) AS LASTDATE
FROM dbo.EMPLOYEE e
INNER JOIN dbo.ASSIGNMENT a ON e.ID = a.EMPLOYEE_ID
INNER JOIN dbo.V_PERSONTOPROFILE pp ON a.ID = pp.assignmentId 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.ATTRIBUTEINSTANCE ai
    INNER JOIN dbo.CODE c ON ai.VALUE = c.CODE
    INNER JOIN dbo.ASSIGNMENT_ATTRIBUTEINSTANCE aai ON ai.ID = aai.attributeInstances_ID 
    ON  a.ID = aai.Assignment_ID
WHERE a.STATUS IN ('A', 'L', 'T')
    AND c.CODEGROUP_ID = 4979
GROUP BY e.EMPLOYEENUMBER, c.DESCRIPTION, a.STATUS
```

It's not an answer (so community wiki), but too big for a comment and changes things in a way that's not necessarily appropriate to do just as an edit.

In the future, try to build the queries more like this in the first place. It's also worth mentioning that queries using RIGHT JOIN can generally be re-written to use LEFT JOIN instead, *and you should do that*:

```
SELECT e.EMPLOYEENUMBER, c.DESCRIPTION, a.STATUS,  
    MAX(a.TIMESTAMP) AS LASTDATE
FROM dbo.ATTRIBUTEINSTANCE ai
INNER JOIN dbo.CODE c ON ai.VALUE = c.CODE
INNER JOIN dbo.ASSIGNMENT_ATTRIBUTEINSTANCE aai ON ai.ID = aai.attributeInstances_ID 
LEFT JOIN dbo.EMPLOYEE e
   INNER JOIN dbo.ASSIGNMENT a ON e.ID = a.EMPLOYEE_ID
   INNER JOIN dbo.V_PERSONTOPROFILE pp ON a.ID = pp.assignmentId 
   ON  a.ID = aai.Assignment_ID
WHERE a.STATUS IN ('A', 'L', 'T')
    AND c.CODEGROUP_ID = 4979
GROUP BY e.EMPLOYEENUMBER, c.DESCRIPTION, a.STATUS
```

Once this is done, we also see the check for `a.Status` effectively forces the OUTER JOIN into an INNER JOIN anyway:

```
SELECT e.EMPLOYEENUMBER, c.DESCRIPTION, a.STATUS,  
    MAX(a.TIMESTAMP) AS LASTDATE
FROM dbo.ATTRIBUTEINSTANCE ai
INNER JOIN dbo.CODE c ON ai.VALUE = c.CODE
INNER JOIN dbo.ASSIGNMENT_ATTRIBUTEINSTANCE aai ON ai.ID = aai.attributeInstances_ID 
INNER JOIN dbo.EMPLOYEE e
   INNER JOIN dbo.ASSIGNMENT a ON e.ID = a.EMPLOYEE_ID
   INNER JOIN dbo.V_PERSONTOPROFILE pp ON a.ID = pp.assignmentId 
   ON  a.ID = aai.Assignment_ID
WHERE a.STATUS IN ('A', 'L', 'T')
    AND c.CODEGROUP_ID = 4979
GROUP BY e.EMPLOYEENUMBER, c.DESCRIPTION, a.STATUS
```

which in turn lets us reorder things so no nesting is needed:

```
SELECT e.EMPLOYEENUMBER, c.DESCRIPTION, a.STATUS,  
    MAX(a.TIMESTAMP) AS LASTDATE
FROM dbo.ATTRIBUTEINSTANCE ai
INNER JOIN dbo.CODE c ON ai.VALUE = c.CODE
INNER JOIN dbo.ASSIGNMENT_ATTRIBUTEINSTANCE aai ON ai.ID = aai.attributeInstances_ID 
INNER JOIN dbo.ASSIGNMENT a ON a.ID = aai.Assignment_ID
INNER JOIN dbo.EMPLOYEE e ON e.ID = a.EMPLOYEE_ID
INNER JOIN dbo.V_PERSONTOPROFILE pp ON a.ID = p.assignmentId 
WHERE a.STATUS IN ('A', 'L', 'T')
    AND c.CODEGROUP_ID = 4979
GROUP BY e.EMPLOYEENUMBER, c.DESCRIPTION, a.STATUS
```

And now that last query is *so much easier* to read, understand, and reason about.

Comment: "I took a moment to reformat the query in a way that's actually readable:" I also am not a fan of the original formatting :)

Answer (score 0):

You can split the status checks up into separate queries and join them with `UNION ALL`. The first part of the query has removed the `MAX()` and `GROUP BY`, as they probably aren't needed for the `A` and `L` status, if I'm understanding correctly. Then I added a `HAVING` cluase to the second part of the query to check for the `LASTDATE` restriction.

```
SELECT
    dbo.EMPLOYEE.EMPLOYEENUMBER
    ,dbo.CODE.DESCRIPTION
    ,dbo.ASSIGNMENT.STATUS
    ,dbo.ASSIGNMENT.TIMESTAMP AS LASTDATE
FROM dbo.EMPLOYEE
INNER JOIN dbo.ASSIGNMENT ON dbo.EMPLOYEE.ID = dbo.ASSIGNMENT.EMPLOYEE_ID
INNER JOIN dbo.V_PERSONTOPROFILE ON dbo.ASSIGNMENT.ID = dbo.V_PERSONTOPROFILE.assignmentId
RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.ATTRIBUTEINSTANCE
INNER JOIN dbo.CODE ON dbo.ATTRIBUTEINSTANCE.VALUE = dbo.CODE.CODE
INNER JOIN dbo.ASSIGNMENT_ATTRIBUTEINSTANCE ON dbo.ATTRIBUTEINSTANCE.ID = dbo.ASSIGNMENT_ATTRIBUTEINSTANCE.attributeInstances_ID ON dbo.ASSIGNMENT.ID = dbo.ASSIGNMENT_ATTRIBUTEINSTANCE.Assignment_ID
WHERE dbo.ASSIGNMENT.STATUS IN ( 'A', 'L')
      AND dbo.CODE.CODEGROUP_ID = 4979

UNION ALL


SELECT
    dbo.EMPLOYEE.EMPLOYEENUMBER
    ,dbo.CODE.DESCRIPTION
    ,dbo.ASSIGNMENT.STATUS
    ,MAX(dbo.ASSIGNMENT.TIMESTAMP) AS LASTDATE
FROM dbo.EMPLOYEE
INNER JOIN dbo.ASSIGNMENT ON dbo.EMPLOYEE.ID = dbo.ASSIGNMENT.EMPLOYEE_ID
INNER JOIN dbo.V_PERSONTOPROFILE ON dbo.ASSIGNMENT.ID = dbo.V_PERSONTOPROFILE.assignmentId
RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.ATTRIBUTEINSTANCE
INNER JOIN dbo.CODE ON dbo.ATTRIBUTEINSTANCE.VALUE = dbo.CODE.CODE
INNER JOIN dbo.ASSIGNMENT_ATTRIBUTEINSTANCE ON dbo.ATTRIBUTEINSTANCE.ID = dbo.ASSIGNMENT_ATTRIBUTEINSTANCE.attributeInstances_ID ON dbo.ASSIGNMENT.ID = dbo.ASSIGNMENT_ATTRIBUTEINSTANCE.Assignment_ID
WHERE dbo.ASSIGNMENT.STATUS IN ('T')
      AND dbo.CODE.CODEGROUP_ID = 4979
GROUP BY dbo.EMPLOYEE.EMPLOYEENUMBER
         ,dbo.CODE.DESCRIPTION
         ,dbo.ASSIGNMENT.STATUS
HAVING MAX(dbo.ASSIGNMENT.TIMESTAMP) > DATEADD(DAY,-60,GETDATE())
```